# Is it possible to integrate google plus' +1 to a Django Website?

Tags: django, facebook-like, google-plus-one, tweets

I wanted to add a +1 button on every post in my website. How do I do that? Any resources? I am also looking for Twitter's Tweet and Facebook's Like. Or Django does not handle that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the [documents](http://developers.google.com/+/plugins/+1button/) for Google Plus, it looks pretty straight forward:

> The simplest way to include a +1 button on your page is by just
>   including the necessary JavaScript and adding a +1 button tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js"></script>
<g:plusone></g:plusone>
```

Comment: yeah. Thanks. http://twitter.com/about/resources/tweetbutton http://www.google.com/webmasters/+1/button/index.html http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/